# Sorting a map of objects C++

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I have a project where I have a game file which contains robots objects. The game file saves the robot objects using a map. The map contains the name of the robot as a key and the value is the robot object.

The robots are in 2D space, and they have x, y to find their current position.

One of the functions I have to implement is to sort the robots from smallest to largest by finding how far they are from the origin point (0, 0).

This is my map:

```
 std::map<std::string, robot> robot_map;
```

I initialize the robot with a  name and two variables to know the location and a third one to find the total amount of steps taken:

```
robot::robot(const string &n) : robot_name(n) { x = 0, y = 0, t = 0; }
```

And to check the robot distance from origin I use this:

```
 std::string game::furthest() const
    {
    int furthest = 0;
    std::string max_name; 

    typedef std::map<std::string, robot>::const_iterator iter;
    for (iter p = robot_map.cbegin(); p != robot_map.cend(); ++p) {

        if (distance(p->second) > furthest) {
            furthest = distance(p->second);
            max_name = p->first;
        }
    }

    return max_name;
    }
```

And this is the distance function:

```
int distance(const robot &r) {
    int distance;
    int y = r.north();
    int x = r.east();

    distance = abs(x - 0) + abs(y - 0);

    return distance;
}
```

In my last function I would like to sort them in a vector, this is what I currently have:

```
std::vector<robot> game::robots_by_travelled() const
{
    std::vector<robot> robots;


    int furthest = 0;

    typedef std::map<std::string, robot>::const_iterator iter;

    for (iter p = robot_map.cbegin(); p != robot_map.cend(); ++p) {
        robots.push_back(p->second);
    }


    return robots;
    ;
}
```

Is there a way to sort the vector by their distance from origin(0, 0)?

Comment: Are you aware of [`std::stort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), especially the overload taking a comparator?

Comment: BTW, `distance` is not Euclidean. Is that right?

Comment: `std::sort(begin(robots), end(robots), [](const robot& r1, const robot& r2) { return distance(r1) < distance(r2); })`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is `std::sort`, which will sort on any appropriate relation:

```
std::sort(robots.begin(), 
          robots.end(),
          [](const robot& lhs, const robot& rhs) 
            { return distance(lhs) < distance(rhs); });
```

or, if you want a reusable predicate:

```
bool closer(const robot& r1, const robot& r2)
{
    return distance(r1) < distance(r2);
}

// ...
std::sort(robots.begin(), robots.end(), closer);
```

You *can* also overload the `<` operator and just say

```
std::sort(robots.begin(), robots.end());
```

but that makes more sense when you have objects that can meaningfully be said to be "less than" each other and you want `<` in other situations as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help.